# Getting id with class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is suppose to show alert of `<a>` element `id` via `class` name when I click it. For some reason I always get `tuto1` alert. What is wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".viewID").click(function() {
    alert($('.viewID').attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="tuto1" class="viewID">Dolor irure velit commodo cillum sit nu</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tuto2" class="viewID">Text, text and more text</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tuto3" class="viewID">consequat occaecat fugiat in adipisicing</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/7ku0f7we/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are accessing the `id` of the first element in the jQuery object.

Use `$(this)` to to access the *clicked* element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wa7x6gLz/)

```
$(".viewID").on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

It's simpler just to access the `id` using `thid.id`, though:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ah4bf5j/)

```
$(".viewID").on('click', function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

---

#### Without jQuery:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/57u803jk/)

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.viewID'), function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could use:

```
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</button>
```

Saves you the jquery part.

JS to alert the ID:

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
```

Cheers,

Valentin

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, you can do this:

```html
<button id="btnId1234" class="btnClass123" onClick="reply_click(this.id, this.className)">Click Me</button>
```

```js
function reply_click(cid, cclass)
{
    console.log(cid);
    console.log(cclass);
}
```